# Test-If not empty, prompt with InputBox for multiplier

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

This is what I'm going for, but I'm pretty green when it comes to loops:

If (G1<>"", InputBox for a multiplier for range G2:G's LastRow,"")

Loop through column BZ1 (or preferably, the last column)

Or:

G1:BZ1 each contain the name of an order set. I need to manually enter the number of times each order set will be used. D2:D1001 are the number of times an item occurs in each set. I need to multiply D2:D1001 by the input box's number and enter that result for each item into G2:G1001.

I have multiple order sets and need to multiple each one by a different number of stores every time that this macro will be run. Order sets are in the columns, items are in the rows.

Comment: If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("mySheetName").Range("G1")) is the test. Are you then wanting to prompt for user input? If so, If Not.... Then multiplier = Application.InputBox("my prompt", Type:= 0). I need to check that last parameter.

Comment: But I am not clear about where you are looping. For example, you are testing G1 but then looping from G2......then what? I think you need to show some data and expected output. The question, as it stands, is too unclear for me to advise further.

Comment: Yes, I need to manually input the multiplier for each column that is being tested.  Also, how can I reference the value of a cell in the text in the input box? So it would read "Number of stores using set **G1**", offsetting one column each time the input box occurs.

Comment: I need to loop the inputbox for each column until the last one with data in row 1, then I need to use the inputted number as a multiplier through the rows in that column.

Comment: you assign the result of the inputbox to a variable e.g. multiplier in my comment above. I am not sure what you mean by would read Number of stories..... unless you mean that as a caption to display with the inputbox?

Comment: i think you mean, you want to loop each column prompting for a multiplier value using inputbox to get user entry. You then want to multiply the entire columns values by that multiplier.

Comment: Sounds like he is using a cell at the top of the column for the multiplier "input box" if that is a case it is just a formula copied down the row. Q2*$Q$1 if it is an input box truly then you need to refer to it as the object that it is to get the value from it as a number and then apply it to every row in the column.  Two different approaches there, one potentially with code.

Comment: I still don't understand the "Number of stores bit" but for the rest.... define the entire range to loop over e.g. A1:B3 and put that in a variable e.g. myRange. Then do a For loop over myRange.Columns prompting with inputbox inside the loop and also doing the multiplication

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code   Ahhhh...... not an InputBox but an input cell.......@TKE-439 Are you expecting the user to type into row 1 and then the column is multiplied by that?

Comment: he is bumping up against the cell has a base value but he wants to apply a changing input box (cell) to it

Comment: @QHarr Yes I want the input box's caption to read "Number of stores using set 1" (text in G1), then on the next loop "Number of stores using set 2" (text in H1)
I believe your last comment is on track for what I am asking.  Using the manually input multiplier (using the input box) I want to multiply the value in each non-empty row of column D.

Comment: G1:BZ1 each contain the name of an order set.  I need to manually enter the number of times each order set will be used.  D2:D1001 are the number of times an item occurs in each set.  I need to multiply D2:D1001 by the input box's number and enter that result for each item into G2:G1001.

Comment: All this detail and some data and layout should be in the question. The answer already posted has much of what you need by the looks of it.

Comment: @QHarr, I apologize for the lack of detail from the start, but I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: Happy to help. I didn’t mean to sound critical and you will get a better response if you [edit] this new info into the question. People can find it more easily and see it within the question context. Also, saves old eyes, like mine, squinting to try and read what is comments. That said, bedtime here in UK. Hope to help again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick - just change that `Sheet1` to whatever your sheet's name is.

So first we get the last column of data to use for our first loop (by getting the value of `lastcol`), then we start looping through the columns. We assign a value to `multiplier` through the `InputBox`, and after that we loop through every cell in the column and multiply it by the number you entered. Then we move on to the next column until we've run out of data.

I've updated the text in the `InputBox` to display the header text for each column each time.

```
Sub Test()

Dim sht As Worksheet, lastcol As Long, lastrow As Long, multiplier As Integer

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastcol = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 7 To lastcol
    If Cells(1, i) <> vbNullString Then
        multiplier = InputBox("Number of stores using set " & Cells(1, i) & ".")
        lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

        For j = 2 To lastrow
            On Error Resume Next
            Cells(j, i).Value = Cells(j, 4).Value * multiplier
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: Usingthemacro]

Comment: vbNullString will be faster than empty string literal. Do they want to ensure Type 0 for numeric inside inputbox? I think...mmmmm....

Comment: multiplier = **Application**.Inputbox...

Also I don't see how to use this value in an equation. I added more clarification to the original comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand several of the components within this code, so I'm not sure how to manipulate it for my needs.

Comment: The `= Application.Inputbox...` returns whatever the input was. That value is assigned to the `multiplier` variable. Inside the `For j = 2 to lastrow` loop, the `multiplier` is multiplied with the value from `cell(j,i)`, then the new value is inserted into back into `cell(j,i)`

Comment: @TKE-439 Did you try using it on your file? Let me explain a bit more in my answer...

Comment: @dwirony Yes I've tried it, but I don't see a result anywhere.  I want to use the input multiplier * $D2:$D1001, and show the result in the same column that triggered the inputbox.

Comment: @TKE-439 So you want to have the column's result equal to the number you enter times the value in column D?

Comment: @dwirony That is correct.  The D column will be constant data that I need to keep in the original form.  The result of this code will communicate increased order quantities for our warehouse.

Comment: @TKE-439 I have edited the code to work from column D

Comment: @dwirony I've copied and pasted your code, updated my sheet name and still, do not see the result.  The input box works perfectly, but once I enter a number, the next box comes up and no data is filled into the sheet.  I'm not sure what could be going wrong at this point.

Comment: Ahh because of the last row value. That should be switched to column D

Comment: @dwirony I was just now able to give your revisions a go, and it worked perfectly for the first column where I needed to see the calculation results, but then I get a "Type Mismatch" error on the line: 

Cells(j,i).Value=Cells(j,4).Value*multiplier

Any suggestions?  Also, thank you so much for getting me this far!

Comment: @TKE-439 So in one of your cells in column D there must be something that isn't a number (hence the type mismatch). Column D is a column of numbers, correct?

Comment: @dwirony The whole sheet was formulas (copying pieces of another sheet), I replaced everything with values, but still get the type mismatch.  All of the calculations fill in for the data that is there, but when it is time for the loop to progress to the next column is where I get the error.  The current sheet carries though row 1001 even though in this case there is only data through row 60.  Should something be done to account for this?

Comment: @TKE-439 And your header row is row 1 right? The numbers start in row 2? I'm convinced something is off by a bit... The amount of rows won't matter as we've established a `lastrow` for this to by dynamic.

Comment: @dwiront That is correct.  I don't know everything about 'lastrow', but when I use control+end it takes me to row 1001, so it looks to me like the code you provided is trying to test formulas/values that return '""'.  I am re-working earlier steps in the code to copy/paste the info I need only through the last row containing original data instead of a formula that carries through row 1001.  I will let you know the results unless you have a better idea.

Comment: @TKE-439 I've edited the code and added some error handling around where you got the error. Try running it now and see what happens. If there are blank spaces messing things up it should just ignore those now.

Comment: @dwirony I didn't use your most recent update, but I got the code before it to work after I revised how the data was coming into the sheet.  If I come across issues with my pieced together code, I will definitely use this most recent code you've provided.  **Thank you so much for all of your help!!**